# How to Write a RegEx function in R that picks countries that have the letter e but not the string ee

Tags: r, regex

This is my first time using stackoverflow (thanks for the help in advance)
I am trying to Write a RegEx function in R that picks countries that have the letter e but not the string ee:

Example:
`countries <- c("USA", "Lebanon", "Greece", "Mexico")`

Desired Output:
"Lebanon", "Mexico"

I tried the below code but no luck:
`str_subset(countries, pattern = "[^ee]e")`

Comment: Use `^(?!.*ee).*e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of the `negate` argument in `str_subset`.

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(countries, pattern = "(?<=(?i)e)((?i)e)|^([^Ee]+)$", 
        negate = TRUE)
#[1] "Lebanon" "Mexico"  "Egypt"   "France"  "FRANCE"
```

Here, we match the case insensitive (`(?i)`) 'e' that follows a case insenstive 'e' (showed in the regex lookaround (`(?<=`) or (`|`) characters that are not a "E" or "e" from the start (`^`) to end (`$`) of the string (essentially matching words with no "E" or "e" character) and use `negate = TRUE` to reverse the matching words

---

Or using `str_count`

```
countries[str_count(countries, "(?<!e)(?i)e(?!=e)") == 1]
#[1] "Lebanon" "Mexico"  "Egypt"   "France"  "FRANCE"
```

EDIT: Included some more edges cases as mentioned by @G5W

#### data

```
countries <- c("USA", "Lebanon", "Greece", "Mexico", "Egypt", "France", "FRANCE")
```

Comment: @G5W Thanks, just was checking the 'France' part, as i didn't see the update